# Excel VBA - How to auto-remove filters after copying information

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I'm currently using excel to do some invoicing. Invoicing records are recorded in a Saleslist.xlsm. Often I need to filter this information, by customer, in order to let the customer know which invoices are currently outstanding, but filtering distorts the file and makes it unusable because new invoices are added to this filtered state and not the original full state.

Therefore I need to find a way to auto-remove the filter, once the individual customer's information has been pulled, through one of the following ways:

- when Saleslist.xlsm is no longer the active workbook
- when Saleslist.xlsm is not the active workbook for more than some arbitrary t seconds.
- when ctrl+c is pressed (but after the original copy function is processed)

I'm not very familiar with vba, but would anyone know which of these is the easiest to implement? Thanks!

Comment: Option 1 is undoubtedly the easiest to implement. Option 2 is probably technically feasible, but practically not a good idea. Option 3 I would also avoid for starters because Ctrl+C is only one of several ways to invoke the exact same "copy" command in Excel, and also because intercepting keystrokes is not usually the best idea. A more robust solution would do the entire process end-to-end (i.e., you determine what inputs are needed to generate the desired outputs, supply the inputs, then a program applies, then removes the filters, and reports whatever you need it to).

Comment: I would make the whole process of filtering, copying, pasting and unfiltering into a macro itself. Then you have complete control over when everything is executed. Is this possible in your scope? Or do we need more information?

Comment: The first one is easiest.

Comment: @girlvsdata I can't really do a whole macro, because the information I want to copy is dependent on context and so varies.